# Object being found by parent class method returning as parent class and not child

Tags: php, object, methods, extends

I have 2 classes - a User class which extend a DatabaseMaster class. i have a create method in the DatabaseMaster class as follows...

```
  public function  create() {
  $attributes = $this->attributes();
  $question_marks = array();
    foreach ($attributes as $key => $value) {
    $question_marks[] = "?";
    }
    $place_holder = array_intersect_key($attributes, get_object_vars($this));
    $place_holder = array_values($place_holder);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO ".static::$table_name." (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_keys($attributes));
    $sql .= ") VALUES (";
    $sql .= join(", ", array_values($question_marks));
    $sql .= ")";
    $query = $handler->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute($place_holder);
}
```

This gets the attributes of the class thats calling it and loops through them in the function to create the SQL string. Works fine.

If I create a new user and for example vardump the user I get....(note I simply put in a visible password as james...the rest are NULL just for explanatory purposes)

```
   object(User)#2 (14) {  
      ["id"]=> NULL ["visible_password"]=> string(5) "James" 
      ["hashed_password"]=> NULL 
      ["temp_hashed_password"]=> NULL 
      ["email"]=> NULL 
      ["first_name"]=> NULL 
      ["last_name"]=> NULL 
      ["position"]=> NULL 
      ["location"]=> NULL
      ["city"]=> NULL 
      ["country"]=> NULL 
      ["institution"]=> NULL 
      ["interests"]=> NULL 
      ["profile_comment"]=> NULL }
```

I also have a find_by_id() method in the DatabaseMaster class....

```
     public static function find_by_id($id=0) {
        $result_array = static::find_by_sql("SELECT * FROM ".static::$table_name." WHERE id={$id} LIMIT 1");
        return !empty($result_array) ? array_shift($result_array) : false;
```

}

Now if i use this on say, id=223 and vardump the result I get....

```
         object(DatabaseMaster)#4 (14) { 
           ["id"]=> string(3) "301" 
           ["visible_password"]=> string(5) "James" 
           ["hashed_password"]=> NULL 
           ["temp_hashed_password"]=> NULL 
           ["email"]=> NULL 
           ["first_name"]=> NULL 
           ["last_name"]=> NULL 
           ["position"]=> NULL 
           ["location"]=> NULL 
           ["city"]=> NULL 
           ["country"]=> NULL 
           ["institution"]=> NULL 
           ["interests"]=> NULL 
           ["profile_comment"]=> NULL }
```

I need this to be coming back as a User object....I can understand why its not (sort of) but as they are static calls in the find_by_id method why is this not a User object....

Your opinions are appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution....

In the find_by_id(); method incorporates another method find_by_sql();

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql){
global $handler;
$query = $handler->query($sql);
$class = get_class($this);
$object_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
return $object_array;
  }
```

Solution was to change this to

```
public static function find_by_sql($sql){
global $handler;
$query = $handler->query($sql);
$class = get_called_class();
$object_array = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, $class);
return $object_array;
```

}